# count all observations after first failure in a day

Tags: r

Following is a sample of my data

```
Customer_id  Seller_id   transaction_date   transaction_status
    1          7           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
    1          7           2010-03-10         FAIL
    1          7           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
    1          8           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
    2          9           2010-03-15         FAIL
    2          9           2010-03-15         FAIL
    3          10          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
    3          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
    3          10          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
    4          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
    4          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
    4          11          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
    5          12          2010-03-20         FAIL
```

I am looking to find the number of transactions between a customer and a seller after their first failed transaction on a given date.

I am fairly familiar with R but have never written any loop in it.
Any help will be great.

Comment: By number of transactions you mean only the "success" cases? How do you want that number / info to be stored? On the same dataset as a column? A different dataset? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks Antonio .. the number of transactions needed under given condition is independent of status (whether it is failed or successful, it doesn't matter.). Yes, It would b great if the solution is column of same dataset.

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer. Any specific format you want your output to be? Do you want to get a new column in your dataset, or just the distinct combinations?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you please tell me what to add in the below code if I wish to calculate the number of transactions till next "n" days after first failed transaction between the customer and seller?

Answer (score 2):

**Example Data**

```
df = read.table(text = "
Customer_id  Seller_id   transaction_date   transaction_status
1          7           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
1          7           2010-03-10         FAIL
1          7           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
1          8           2010-03-10         SUCCESS
2          9           2010-03-15         FAIL
2          9           2010-03-15         FAIL
3          10          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
3          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
3          10          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
4          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
4          10          2010-03-15         FAIL
4          11          2010-03-15         SUCCESS
5          12          2010-03-20         FAIL
", header=T)
```

**Solution** (using `dplyr` and not `for` loops)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Customer_id, Seller_id, transaction_date) %>%
  mutate(transaction_count = sum((transaction_status == "SUCCESS" & cumsum(transaction_status == "FAIL") > 0) |
                                 (transaction_status == "FAIL" & cumsum(transaction_status == "FAIL") > 1))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 13 x 5
#   Customer_id Seller_id transaction_date transaction_status transaction_count
#         <int>     <int> <fct>            <fct>                          <int>
# 1           1         7 2010-03-10       SUCCESS                            1
# 2           1         7 2010-03-10       FAIL                               1
# 3           1         7 2010-03-10       SUCCESS                            1
# 4           1         8 2010-03-10       SUCCESS                            0
# 5           2         9 2010-03-15       FAIL                               1
# 6           2         9 2010-03-15       FAIL                               1
# 7           3        10 2010-03-15       SUCCESS                            1
# 8           3        10 2010-03-15       FAIL                               1
# 9           3        10 2010-03-15       SUCCESS                            1
#10           4        10 2010-03-15       FAIL                               1
#11           4        10 2010-03-15       FAIL                               1
#12           4        11 2010-03-15       SUCCESS                            0
#13           5        12 2010-03-20       FAIL                               0
```

*Note* that the above solution keeps the same number of rows as your original dataset.

If you add `... %>% distinct(Customer_id, Seller_id, transaction_date, transaction_count)` at the end of the previous code you'll get distinct combinations like:

```
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#   Customer_id Seller_id transaction_date transaction_count
#         <int>     <int> <fct>                        <int>
# 1           1         7 2010-03-10                       1
# 2           1         8 2010-03-10                       0
# 3           2         9 2010-03-15                       1
# 4           3        10 2010-03-15                       1
# 5           4        10 2010-03-15                       1
# 6           4        11 2010-03-15                       0
# 7           5        12 2010-03-20                       0
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(Customer_id,Seller_id, transaction_date) %>% 
  mutate(postfail=lag(transaction_status=="FAIL")) %>% 
  fill(postfail) %>% summarize(postfail_transactions=sum(postfail, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   Customer_id [?]
  Customer_id Seller_id postfail_transactions
        <int>     <int>                 <int>
1           1         7                     1
2           1         8                     0
3           2         9                     1
4           3        10                     1
5           4        10                     1
6           4        11                     0
7           5        12                     0
```

Note that I count *any* transaction after the first fail (including further failures).

Remove the last step if you want the information as just another column in the same dateframe.

Comment: ..Thanks for the solution. Could you please tell me what to add in the above code if I wish to calculate the number of transactions till next "n" days after first failed transaction between the customer and seller?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a count of all successes after the first fail `count_success`, and also all transactions after the first fail `count_all`

`.N` is the number of rows in the current group, and `which.max(fail)` gives the first occurrence for which `fail` is `TRUE`, so `.N - which.max(fail)` gives the number of rows (transactions) after the first failure.

The number of successes is counted as the sum of a logical vector which is `TRUE` if the row number `seq(.N)` is greater than the row number of the first fail `which.max(fail)`, and fail is `FALSE`, i.e. `!fail`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# Number of Successful transactions after first failure
df[, {fail <- transaction_status == 'FAIL'
      .(count_all      = .N - which.max(fail), 
        count_success  = sum(!fail & (seq(.N) > which.max(fail))))}
   , by = .(Customer_id, Seller_id, transaction_date)]

#    Customer_id Seller_id transaction_date count_all count_success
# 1:           1         7       2010-03-10         1             1
# 2:           1         8       2010-03-10         0             0
# 3:           2         9       2010-03-15         1             0
# 4:           3        10       2010-03-15         1             1
# 5:           4        10       2010-03-15         1             0
# 6:           4        11       2010-03-15         0             0
# 7:           5        12       2010-03-20         0             0
```